# Doctrine querybuilder where element is child of a doctrine nested set tree parent

Tags: php, symfony, tree, doctrine, nested-sets

I want to build a querybuilder that return elements which have at a certain point a given element in their parents.

Doubling on the parent or using root is not fine because there might be multiple levels.

So far I have this code :

```
return = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->leftJoin('o.organizationCategories', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.parent', 'parent')
        ->where('parent = ?2')
        ->orWhere('parent.parent = ?2')
        ->setParameter(2, $parent)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Of course if the parent is not the root parent nor the grandparent not the parent this does not work anymore.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following

```
/**
 * ProductRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
abstract class HasCategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @return QueryBuilder
     */
    abstract function getExplorerQueryBuilder();

    /**
     * Filters products on ingredients, which belong to the category 'consommable'
     *
     * @param ObjectCategory $objectCategory
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
     */
    public function findByTopCategoryQueryBuilder($objectCategory)
    {
        $objectCategoryRepository = $this->_em->getRepository('AppBundle:Core\ObjectCategory');

        if (!$objectCategory instanceof ObjectCategory) $objectCategory=$objectCategoryRepository->findOneBy(array('slug' => $objectCategory));
        if (!$objectCategory) throw new \Exception("La catégorie n'a pas été trouvée.");

        $queryBuilder = $this->getExplorerQueryBuilder();

        $categories = array_merge(array($objectCategory), $objectCategoryRepository->children($objectCategory));
        $categoriesIds = array_map(function(BaseCategoryClass $category){return $category->getid();}, $categories);

        $queryBuilder = $queryBuilder
                ->andWhere($this->createQueryBuilder('object')->expr()->in('c.id', $categoriesIds))
            ;

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
}
```